# Amazon APIGateway Android SDK Example - Tutorial

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, aws-api-gateway

Anyone know of an example or tutorial on what to do with the Android SDK that you download for your AWS APIGateway?  It is a template of Empty objects and calls to all of your APIGateway methods.  Not sure what to do to the downloaded file (that uses Maven to build a jar) in order for it to return JSON objects the way that the AWS Dashboard does.  The Android documentation does not reflect the current state of AndroidStudio in its steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you gone through this? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html#how-to-generate-sdk-android

The 'Empty' object you see is the default one that is included with the 200 response, but to actually build a useful SDK you need to write your own Models and attach them to the method requests/responses. There are several examples here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/example-photos.html

As far as integrating it into your project, you need to build it with Maven then use the SDK similar to the example code in the first doc link.

Comment: hey@jack-kohn, yes I've been through that documentation.  Its the AWS console side.  I need the Android Example and that document doesn't show that. For the life of me I can't figure out why they don't have an example of what the Android file looks like when the console mapping looks like that.

Comment: If you look at that documentation, it shows:

    // Invoke your parentPath1Get method.
OriginalModel output = client.parentPath1Get(param1,body);

yet it does not show you the parentPath1Get model, what param1, or body are?

Comment: If you have any parameters on the Method Request (parameters being path, query string, or header) those show up by name in the arguments to the method. If you have a request model, usually in a POST or PUT, those also show up as arguments. If you have a response model that will be the return type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jack.  Can you elaborate?  If this is what is in the AWS Generated Templte, 
` @com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.annotation.Operation(path = "/drips", method = "GET")
    Empty dripsGet();
    ` and I create a client with the factory method and then call client.dripsGet(), I should get back a JSON object.  Does the client.dripsGet() need to be handled on a thread? I don't see a completion block or JSON object that is to be returned?  Where do I put my implimentation to handle the results?

Comment: in the example like you gave me, what would the Android method actually look like (the example page is just the json output.  What would the actual Android Code look like).  Do I update the template and then recompile it into the code again with Maven?

Comment: You should only have to build once with Maven. If you're making changes to the API itself then you should regenerate the SDK because it will sync up new parameters/models. The way you consume the client is up to you; the example in the docs is pretty generic but it should apply. The second doc link I posted is describing how to write Models, which turn into native POJOs when you generate the SDK. In the Android example code you can see the client returns an instance of 'OriginalModel'.

Comment: Hey @jack, I think there in my be part of the problem. There are no models. The iOS guys didn't use them so I think they built it all inside of the app once the ios SDK was downloaded - sound like a possibility?  If I can not generate the models in the console (I don'f have access), how do I go about it with just the Empty template?  I guess I'm just old school and expect the JSON at the top of your second example to come back as a string which I would then feed to a JSON Object and go from there.  Since I don't have models in the console where do I go from here?

Comment: So AWS finally gave me a template and explained that if I got the JSON response I could use a JSON builder like JSON Model Generator Plugin for Android.  Once created I could then use that to create a class and use that as the reponse in the AWS Generated SDK.  Again this would be automatic if the models were inside the GateWay dashboard, however in my case they are not and I do not have the admin rights to do so.  AWS is updating their docs.  Thanks all!